# Gnome Tweaks - Applications - Shell Themes Folder

Tags: themes, settings, gnome-shell, gnome-tweak-tool

I would like to know what for is this icon (None ^|) between the texts "shell" and "mininal-conception" in the attached image.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Gnome Tweak Tool.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "**(None)**" button is for installing themes manually from `.zip` archives.

If you have a `.zip` file containing a GNOME shell theme you can select and "install" the theme using the "**(None)**" button, then load it from the drop-down list ("*mininal-conception*" in your screenshot) next to it.

The archive gets extracted to your `~/.local/share/themes/` directory. If you want to remove the theme from the drop-down list, just delete the corresponding folder from `~/.local/share/themes/`.